# How to install Magento using XAMPP

Tags: magento, xampp

I'm trying to install Magento but I have a problem on this [page](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik=9f4f37025c&view=fimg&th=147d068d5b35d42b&attid=0.1&disp=inline&realattid=f_hysxgt920&safe=1&attbid=ANGjdJ-tVdzLNtBpk_foOletH_BhUTozrTKf7qJdk6FfcDYdhmw1DvwjBZX_zYZPMRipaahgQZvs9aPU06amZ12VAFigewh2VfZFg2TjBct8BWhRyntJdpNaGKe3QXE&ats=1408036041603&rm=147d068d5b35d42b&zw&sz=w1723-h738).
Indeed, when I click on the button *Continue*, the page simply reloads without any changes.

I'm using XAMPP on a mac and mysql installation is in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/. I've created the magento database. And the following commands works :

```
$ /Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysql -u root
$ use magento;
$ select 1 from test;
```

I've added this alias

```
alias mysql="/Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysql"
```

In case Magento didn't find the mysql installation but I've still the error.

Do you know how to solve this bug ? Or do you know where are the log file ?

Answer (score 0):

Are all XAMPP services on? Including the MySql One?

Comment: All the services are on. And the mysql too.

Comment: I replaced localhost by 127.0.0.1 but now I got this error 
    Database server does not support the InnoDB storage engine.
When i look at the log I see 
    sh: mysql: command not found
While I've put the change for the path in the .bashrc
    export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH